# R- Please help. Having trouble writing for loop to lag date

Tags: r, date, loops, for-loop, lag

I am attempting to write a for loop which will take subsets of a dataframe by person id  and then lag the EXAMDATE variable by one for comparison. So a given row will have the original EXAMDATE and also a variable EXAMDATE_LAG which will contain the value of the EXAMDATE one row before it.

```
for (i in length(uniquerid))
{
    temp <- subset(part2test, RID==uniquerid[i])
    temp$EXAMDATE_LAG <- temp$EXAMDATE
    temp2 <- data.frame(lag(temp, -1, na.pad=TRUE))  
    temp3 <- data.frame(cbind(temp,temp2))
}
```

It seems that I am creating the new variable just fine but I know that the lag won't work properly because I am missing steps. Perhaps I have also misunderstood other peoples' examples on how to use the lag function?

Comment: Could you please provide some example data (`part2test`)?

Comment: This sounds like a good case for `plyr` or `data.table`. `library(plyr); ddply(part2test, .(uniquerid), transform, EXAMDATE_LAG=lag(EXAMDATE, -1, na.pad=TRUE))` or something like that.

Comment: Don't use the lag() function. Time-series function in R are difficult to understand. If this is a Date-class variable just subtract 1 or shift with c(temp$EXAMDATE[-1], NA), depending on what you mean..

Comment: +1 to @Dwin 's comment.  I'd use something like my code and replace the `lag(...)` with his version.

Comment: You are overwriting temp each iteration, it isn't really itereating because there's no sequence.

Answer (score 1):

So that this can be fully answered.  There are a handful of things wrong with your code.  Lucaino has pointed one out.  Each time through your loop you are going to create `temp`, `temp2`, and `temp3` (or overwrite the old one). and thus you'll be left with only the output of the last time through the loop.

However, this isnt something that needs a loop.  Instead you can make use of the vectorized nature of `R`

```
x <- 1:10

> c(x[-1], NA)
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA
```

So if you combine that notion with a library like `plyr` that splits data nicely you should have a workable solution.  If I've missed something or this doesn't solve your problem, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

```
library(plyr)
myLag <- function(x) {
  c(x[-1], NA)
}

ddply(part2test, .(uniquerid), transform, EXAMDATE_LAG=myLag(EXAMDATE))
```

You could also do this in base R using `split` or the `data.table` package using its `by=` argument.